# Why is LogCat still reporting even after I have removed the Log.foo(outputs)?

Tags: java, android, debugging, logcat, android-logcat

I am really freaked out right now by this "ghost code".
I had some

```
Log.d("debug","Insert message here");
```

lines in my code that helped me debug. After I removed those lines, or commented them out, they STILL show up in the LogCat console. What is going on? Does anyone else have this happening to them?

I have searched through the code manually, used ctrl+f, cleaned up code, reinstalled my app, etc., and it's still happening.

Comment: Add this line again, but this time change the message. Like Log.d("debug2","Insert message here2"); and see if this appears?

Comment: @Arslan Afzal Shoot...I just ran the Project Clean and corrupted my code. I need to update the SDK build tools now and fix this first.

Comment: Oh for the love of god, Eclipse is sending me in a loop here fixing one problem after another. Now I'm getting adb errors. Gonna have to fix that too. =_=

Comment: Can you see the file R.java is available in your project?

Comment: (Update: I fixed everything, it's all good now.) Hey, apparently adding that new Log.d(out) cleared it! Thanks a lot. :D Now I'm just wondering why it happened...

Comment: What I still think is, that was just a debug idea. Your problem was that eclipse was not rebuilding your project on each new build.

Comment: @ArslanAfzal You should post an official answer. And perhaps an explanation if you can. I'll select your answer.

Comment: I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think about it that Eclipse is not re-building the project on every run. So even you have removed the syntax line, it is still available in old compilation.
What I got for you a debug idea.

Add another line.  nearby the old one, that you are saying you have removed.

```
Log.d("debug2","Insert message here2");
```

If you see this new line in Logcat then you must have the old one somewhere in your code.
If you can't see this line, then I'm right, eclipse is not making the fresh re-build. In this case, do project >> clean and re-build.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have connected 2 devices, e.g. emulator and real android device.
In that case there is possibility that logs are generated from one of those devices (which include "old" code with logs) while you build and run other device?

If it is somehow true, go to DDMS view and select proper device.

Comment: I actually did have an emulator as well as a real world device running the code. How do I "select" the device to use from the DDMS?
Edit: My emulator is actually offline though. Why would it be reporting from an offline device's code?

Comment: In DDMS there is device window (if it's not, you can find it via Window > Show view > Devices in Eclpise), there will be listed all connected devices.

Comment: There is only one connected device--my phone.

Comment: Nevermind, I have fixed the problem. Thanks for the tip though--I'll keep an eye out for this scenario if it happens again!